# Reading advertisement packet using QtBluetooth

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, qtbluetooth

Is there any way to read the contents of an advertisement packet advertised by a BLE device(peripheral) on BLE Central application developed in Qt using QtBluetooth.